# concrete5 CMS cannot parse PATH_INFO information from my server

Tags: php, content-management-system, blogs, concrete5

I am trying to install a popular and open source CMS called concrete5.

I've just uploaded the source files for the CMS to the server. Now, when I go to the test screen that test requirements from my server it says that my server does NOT **"Support concrete5 request URLS"**. Under help is says that means:

> concrete5 cannot parse the PATH_INFO or ORIG_PATH_INFO information provided by my server.

It will not allow me to finish the installation until this issue is resolved.

[image: See, I can't install until I get my server to "Support concrete5 request URLs"]

For some background information, I am hosting my site with GoDaddy, Linux OS, and PHP Version 5.3. 
I can tell you any other information you need to know on request, just let me know!

You can also visit the installation page that screenshot was taken from if you like. It is @ blog.texasca.com/concrete5.5.2.1

Any people who can think of likely solutions to this problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer was to add a php5.ini file inside of the root folder with the following code

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

BOOM! That simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a url-rewrite issue. You need to check if there's an .htaccess file in your root like the one here: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/using-concrete5/dashboard/system-and-maintenance/seo-and-statistics/pretty-urls/ - if not, create it and try again. If you have it and the urls still don't work, you'll need to contact your host and ask for the following:

- mod_rewrite enabled
- allow override for your hosts